# How can I deduce whether the address at hand is part of an array, from a trace?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

**This question is concerning low level programming and the solutions for C,C++ etc. does not apply here**

I know that if you go through the ELF file you can see global arrays as chunky symbols. How does the processor know that the address is part of an array ? As all it sees are addresses with no specific metadata. Or is there some way this information is passed down to lower levels ?

Eg:

```
55: 0000000000201078     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _end
56: 0000000000000540    43 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _start
57: 0000000000201070     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 __bss_start
58: 000000000000064a    49 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 main
59: 0000000000201020    80 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 test_Var
60: 0000000000201070     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    23 __TMC_END__
```

The above section is a **readelf -s** output. Since I wrote the code I know line 59 is referring to the global array test_Var. But how will I know some data in an instruction I encounter while simulating this code say on Gem5 or running a PIN tool, is part of this array. Not to mention I cannot even see local arrays at this stage. So the question is if I have an instruction trace, or even a data trace of this program, how can I know this particular array is involved at a given instance ?

Comment: There is a difference in local data (placed on the stack), and global symbols. The linker can find global symbols and assign a VMA to it. Local data, however, doesn't even exist literally until runtime, because it has to be actively allocated on the stack. Similar story with dynamic/heap memory.

Comment: The processor does not know what array or other object an address is part of.  It doesn't need to know that to execute the program.

Comment: Arrays are high level language concepts, so only thing relevant is programming languages like C, C++ etc with respect to that term.  They have no meaning whatsoever to a processor.

Comment: How does a nail know it is part of a house?  Or a shed?  Or a deck? Or with other nails in a box or tray?  It doesnt the high level creator of that project knows, at the low level it is just a nail.

Answer (score 2):

All the metadata the processor needs is encoded within the machine code instructions that it executes.  And if the processor needs the same information at different times for different parts of the program, the compiler will repeat any necessary metadata in the instructions of all such parts of the program.

The kind of metadata the processor needs is: how big is the item (e.g. byte, half, word, quad), is an item signed or unsigned, how far to skip ahead for each index position of an array, etc..  And generally speaking, the processor requires instruction sequences to get any high level language code done, so some metadata is effectively encoded within individual instructions as well as by the sequences of instructions themselves.

An example here is an array that has a particular data type, and of course, is used (e.g. indexed) read & written in different parts of the program.  The C program encodes type information (metadata) within the C array declaration, and this type holds no matter what function is accessing the array.  However, the processor does not read data declarations, only machine code instructions!   So, the translation repeats the size and access pattern information with machine code instructions and instruction sequences as needed, and thus, the compiler ensures consistent access by the processor.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't; this is the point of undefined behaviour in C / C++: compiler assumes the programmer is right and just does what the source code says.  If that leads to accessing a different object that was nearby in memory, that's the programmer's fault, not the compiler's or the CPUs.

**We gain efficiency by not even trying to detect this at runtime.**

Comment: Ok, let me re-phrase this; if I recreate the assembly from ELF using objdump or something similiar; how can I identify an array without relying on metadata ??

Comment: @FebinSunny: That's an entirely different question.  Are you talking only about static arrays?  Not whether some function arg passed to `void foo(int*)` is a pointer to a scalar or array?

Comment: @FebinSunny: Oh, you said *without* metadata.  Then it's not very different from the general case; you have to reverse engineer to see if the code loops over contiguous addresses, or uses an integer to index into memory.  Either with math instructions or with an addressing mode.  If you see an addressing mode with an absolute address and an index register, you can be pretty sure that's a static array.  Like `mov eax, [0x600234 + rdx*4]`

Comment: is rdx supposed to be there for all static arrays ? If so I can track that using PIN or something I suppose !! Obviously I am considering the scenario where I have the executable for an application at hand and I have to track arrays in there !!

Comment: @FebinSunny: no, of course not; the compiler could have used any register as an index, and the scale factor could be anything.  It might even be accessed only with compile-time-constant indices as `[RIP + constant]`.  Off the top of my head I can't think of an algorithm that's anywhere *near* complete without huge possibility of false-positives, although most addressing modes with 2 registers or a scaled index will be accessing arrays.  But you'll need runtime register values to figure out which register is the base and which is the index if the 2nd reg has no scale factor.

Comment: In general, you cannot find out where objects begin and end in memory without metadata.  That's why decompiling programs is so hard.

Comment: even with metadata it may be difficult, at this point the information has been lost as it is not relevant.  arrays, etc are entities in the eyes of a programmer at the high level language level,  the processor is incredibly dumb it only does what it is told.  data, pointers, integers, floating point numbers, instructions, etc are just bits to the processor they have no meaning whatsoever.  just bits. except for the brief clock or few where they are interpreted and executed. but even with an add instruction the bits could be integers, pointers, addresses, to you, but to the processor just bits.

Comment: @FebinSunny: I added the reverse-engineering tag to your question.  The phrasing is still not at all clear that you're asking from that angle so I suggest you modify it.  Or ask a different question, since what you want really *is* a different question.  Looking at what running code does doesn't give any definitive signal every time any array is accessed, even if we count only arrays that aren't optimized away at compile time.